# Is it possible to creating a custom Videoplayer and place it in a View on Android?

Tags: android, media-player

I have been searching around for any info on creating a video player. Here is what I am looking for, I want to create a player to play videos (stream preferably) with my own custom playback buttons. The player will be set in a View (size of the view varies). Can i do this with just the MediaPlayer class, and can i add it in a View. If there are any examples or tutorials. I would greatly appreciate it. Thankx again in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the most straight forward way of controlling a video is using the mediaController class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html

This can ether be anchored to a mediaPlayer or a VideoView. Both of these support streaming and since mediaController is a Widget it can be customized.

This should be enough unless you looking to do something really out there with the controller.

Hope this helps